# Issue with Invocable Method to Call Queueable

Tags: null-pointer, invocable-method, queueable-apex

Ok, I'm officially confused. I've written some code to attempt to populate a Campaign lookup field on Opportunity based on some logic. The basic flow is Process Builder (so the client can declaratively change when the logic fires if desired) > Invocable Method > Queueable.

My code works just fine in the context of my unit tests, but when I try to test it in sandbox I get a null-pointer exception.

Invocable:

```
public class PrimaryCampaign {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void setPrimaryCampaign(List<Id> oppIds){
        System.debug(oppIds); //populated
        System.enqueueJob(new PrimaryCampaignQueueable(oppIds));
    }

}
```

Simplified Queueable:

```
public class PrimaryCampaignQueueable implements Queueable{

    public static List<Id> oppList;

    public PrimaryCampaignQueueable(List<Id> oppIds){
        oppList = oppIds;
    }

    public static void execute(QueueableContext qc){
        System.debug(oppList); //NPE occurs here, but when I run unit tests, this is populated
        //do logic
    }

}
```

Simplified Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class TestPrimaryCampaign {

    @testSetup
    static void setUp(){

        //set up data including Accounts, Contacts, Campaigns, CampaignMembers, Opportunities & OpportunityContactRoles
    }

    @isTest
    static void testPrimaryCampaign(){
        List<Id> oppIds = new List<Id>();
        Opportunity o = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity];
        oppIds.add(o.Id);
        Test.startTest();
        PrimaryCampaign.setPrimaryCampaign(oppIds);
        Test.stopTest();

        //do assertions
    }

}
```

I've tried testing both through the UI to trigger the Process Builder, as well as just running the following anonymous block in the dev console getting the same NPE both ways:

```
List<Id> oppIds = new List<Id>();
oppIds.add('0062F000002USgZQAW');
PrimaryCampaign.setPrimaryCampaign(oppIds);
```

I also tried making the oppList not static and defining it with:

```
this.oppList = oppIds;
```

But that fails to compile with an error that the variable oppList doesn't exist. I am so confused. What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your oppList shouldn't be static.

It should be a member variable.

Try this:

```
public List<Id> oppList;
```

Note how you are creating a new Queueable in this line:

```
System.enqueueJob(new PrimaryCampaignQueueable(oppIds));
```

**EDIT**: I was right, but for a partly wrong reason.

As @sfdcfox says, it's because the static member is not serialized when the `Queueable` is serialized prior to processing.

When the execute method is called (by the system), the Queueable is rehydrated and the oppList, being static is lost - which is why it ends up null.

Here is the relevant documentation:

> The Queueable interface behaves a lot like the Batchable interface. It gives you a class structure that we can serialize for you, and you can serialize more than just primitive arguments. It is called by a method, System.enqueueJob(), which returns a job ID to you.

[developer documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/10/new-apex-queueable-interface.html)

Comment: Also the execute method shouldn't be static either.

Comment: @DavidCheng You can access static members from non-static code, but you can't access non-static members from static code. It compiles just fine, but only non-static, non-transient variables will be serialized.